# ERROR Android Studio SQLite table "inventory" has no column named "quantity"

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I know its simple and I am just new to SQLite and Android Studio, but I am trying to create a database table inventory each item having an ID, item name, and quantity. Then view that database table in RecyclerView. Right now I am getting the error message:

```
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting item=Apples _id=1 quantity=5
         android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table inventory has no column named quantity 
         (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO inventory(item,_id,quantity) VALUES 
         (?,?,?)
```

Here is my current code:

IventoryDB.java

```
    private static final class InventoryTable {
        private static final String TABLE = "inventory";
        private static final String COL_ID = "_id";
        private static final String COL_ITEM = "item";
        private static final String COL_QTY = "quantity";
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + InventoryTable.TABLE + " (" +
                InventoryTable.COL_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                InventoryTable.COL_ITEM + " text, " +
                InventoryTable.COL_QTY + "text)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
                          int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + InventoryDB.InventoryTable.TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addItem(int id, String item, String qty) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(InventoryDB.InventoryTable.COL_ID, id);
        values.put(InventoryDB.InventoryTable.COL_ITEM, item);
        values.put(InventoryDB.InventoryTable.COL_QTY, qty);

        db.insert(InventoryDB.InventoryTable.TABLE, null, values);
    }
```

Inventory.java

```
    private AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder;
    private AlertDialog dialog;
    private InventoryDB DB;
    private int id;

    public void addItem(View view) {
        createNewAddItemDialog();
    }

    public void createNewAddItemDialog(){
        dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final View addItemPopupView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_additem, null);
        addItemName = (EditText)  addItemPopupView.findViewById(R.id.additempopup_itemname);
        addItemQuantity = (EditText)addItemPopupView.findViewById(R.id.additempopup_itemquantity);
        addItemBtn = (Button) addItemPopupView.findViewById(R.id.additempopup_add);
        cancelAddBtn = (Button) addItemPopupView.findViewById(R.id.additempopup_cancel);

        dialogBuilder.setView(addItemPopupView);
        dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        dialog.show();

        addItemBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String itemName = addItemName.getText().toString();
            String itemQuantity = addItemQuantity.getText().toString();
            if (itemName.equals("") || itemQuantity.equals("")) {
                //addError.setText("Please ensure both fields are filled out!");
            } else {
                Boolean itemExists = DB.checkItemExists(itemName);
                if (itemExists){
                //addError.setText("Item already exists!");
                } else {
                    DB.addItem(id, itemName, itemQuantity);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    id += 1;
                }
            }
        });

        cancelAddBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> dialog.dismiss());
    }
```

popup_additem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Item"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.25" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/additempopup_itemname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Item Name"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.361" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/additempopup_itemquantity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Item Quantity"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/additempopup_itemname"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.066" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/additempopup_add"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Add"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.8"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/additempopup_itemquantity"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.105" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/additempopup_cancel"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Cancel"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/additempopup_add"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.8"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/additempopup_itemquantity"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.105" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a long shot, but I think that you're missing a blank space in the last sentence of the method `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)` ... it seems that you're creating a column named: `quantitytext` instead of `quantity text` ...

Comment: Thank you, and i knew it would be something silly. Just has to put that space, uninstall and reinstall and it worked. Ive been pulling my hair out for 2 hours because of a space xD